# .Net Core 2.0 - OpenID Connect - invalid Discovery Document

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-2.0, openid-connect

i'm using a specific OIDC provider for my security in .Net Core 2.0 MVC Project, however I am having trouble with the Discovery Document.

I have been given 3 url's from the provider (where the domain is fiction):

> https://www.oidcprovider.com/connectapi/authorize
>
> https://www.oidcprovider.com/connectapi/token
>
> https://www.oidcprovider.com/connectapi/userinfo

in my configuration, i have entered the following values:

```
 .AddOpenIdConnect(options => {
                    options.Authority = "https://www.oidcprovider.com/connectapi/authorize/";
                    options.ClientId = "xxx";
                    options.ClientSecret = "xxx";
                    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
                    options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/api/security/callback");
```

I am getting the following error, trying to run the application:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).
>   System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
>
> IOException: IDX10804: Unable to retrieve document from:
>   'https://www.oidcprovider.com/connectapi/authorize/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever+d__8.MoveNext()
>
> InvalidOperationException: IDX10803: Unable to obtain configuration
>   from:
>   'https://www.oidcprovider.com/connectapi/authorize/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager+d__24.MoveNext()

**Is the OIDC Discovery Document required for this to work?**

I have tried calling the discovery document URL directly in my browser, by calling this url: https://www.oidcprovider.com/connectapi/authorize/.well-known/openid-configuration

However, I receive this JSON information back:

> {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"No client id supplied"}

How do I get this to work?

**My 2 Questions are:**

**1. Is the Discovery Document Optional or Mandatory ?**

**2. Can I specify the endpoints manually in .net Core 2.0 when no disco doc is available?**

Comment: Have you tried to put different url into  options.Authority?  The https://www.oidcprovider.com/connectapi/authorize/ is most likely wrong. Try using either https://www.oidcprovider.com/connectapi or https://www.oidcprovider.com

Comment: According to the spec (https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html#ProviderMetadata) this shold be at the root of the Hostname: GET /.well-known/openid-configuration HTTP/1.1
  Host: example.com

Comment: Thomas - it seems the discovery document is not available at the url's you suggested, only at the /authorize url. But giving me back the JSON Error.

Comment: jwilleke - So, you are saying, that this Provider has not implemented the OpenID Connect protocol properly?

Answer (score 3):

Seems like I have found my answers.

1. The discovery document is Optional.
2. Yes - you can by specifying the Configuration options in the .AddOpenIdConnect options

   options.Configuration = new OpenIdConnectConfiguration()
                   {
                       AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://www.oidcprovider.com/connectapi/authorize",
                       TokenEndpoint = "https://www.oidcprovider.com/connectapi/token",
                       UserInfoEndpoint = "https://www.oidcprovider.com/connectapi/userinfo"
                   };